# Azure is not creating database schema on publish of EFCore 2 application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Publishing ASPNetCore app to Azure, with associated data DLL.

Azure is not picking up any databases on the publishing wizard, but is picking up the DbContext, and the connection string from DbContext.

I've declared the connection string and DbProvider (SqlServer) in the `Startup.cs` and `DbContext`, it's also declared as an environment variable within the service app.

The publishing wizard looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE1IW.png).

After publishing through the wizard the app service deploys successfully, but the APIs all hit 500 server errors.

The build output contains several messages, that to me look like successes.

> `Generating Entity framework SQL Scripts...`
>
> `Executing command: dotnet ef migrations script --idempotent --out "./path"`
>
> `Generating Entity framework SQL Scripts completed successfully`
>
> `adding database .. connstr`

Do I need to create migrations for an initial create of the application?

I've been using the Code First paradigm method in EFCore, and so I have `EnsureDeleted` and `EnsureCreated` in some initializers for testing, but these aren't called at runtime.

I also have an `EnsureCreated` within the `Startup.cs`.

```
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production")
            {
                services.AddDbContext<FFDbContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection")));
            }
            else
            {
                services.AddDbContext<FFDbContext>(options =>
                       options.UseSqlServer(local connections string));
            }

            // Automatically perform database migration
            services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<FFDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

            var context = services.BuildServiceProvider()
                .GetRequiredService<FFDbContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

I feel like if anything I'm over compensating for trying to create the db, any ideas?

#### Edit - SQL Error from Azure Insights

> ```
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
> ```

Comment: Have you checked in SQL Management Studio if the tables are created or not? And have you checked the error details why do you get 500 error when you call the API? Can you share the error message?

Comment: I have checked SSMS the tables are not creating. I can definitely share the error message which would be most appropriate to see? I'm unsure how to properly access messages within Azure. I can see the error.htm pages, and the event viewer. Although the event viewer doesnt show any errors.

Comment: Have you deployed your application as an App Service? If yes, then you can set up Application insights and check the errors there, you can check the logs in Kudu, which is available at <your site name>.scm.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Oh I hadn't realize error availability on Insights. The tables do not exist in the database, they're not creating upon deployment of the EFCore application. I have edited the original post to include a sample of the SQL error within Azure insights. Thank you.

Comment: Is firewall configured correctly for your azure sql instance ? Did you allow service from azure to use azure sql . It's switch under firewall !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your DefaultConnection in both of below files:

`appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`

Change this

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=webapi;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

To

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=WebApiEfCore;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

run the below queries:

```
dotnet ef migrations add initial
dotnet ef database update
```

Also you can try using Visual studio too and see if it helps.

Comment: What I was missing was the `dotnet ef migrations add initial` statement. I hadn't generated any migrations for Azure DB to use, as I thought it would work as it worked in local development, where the database is generated using the DbContext.

Comment: Gld to know it helped.